# Error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I don't know why I am getting this error. I think I have closed every bracket.

I tried making the id letters instead of numbers.

```
function check(x,y) {
    coor = "'" + x + y + "'";
    if (document.getElementById(coor).classList.contains("bomb")) {
        document.getElementById('WoL').innerHTML = "You lose.";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "grid-square" onclick = "check(1,8)" id = "18">?</div>
```

I expect the output to make the paragraph with id "WoL" say "You lose." if you click on the div and it is a bomb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check(x,y) {
    coor = x.toString() + y.toString();
    if (document.getElementById(coor).classList.contains("bomb")) {
        document.getElementById('WoL').innerHTML = "You lose.";
    }
}

check(1,1);
```

```html
<div id="WoL"></div>
<div class="bomb" id="11">A tile containing a bomb</div>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. It still thinks that the element is null.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work. I just had to put the script tag at the end of the body instead of the head.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping your string in quotes, and so, at the moment you are really looking for an element with the id of `'18'` not `18` (thus giving you `null`). Instead, you can either concatenate `x` and `y` with an empty string or use the `String()` method to convert your numbers into a string.

You'll also need to add the class `bomb` to your div to pass your `if` statement check.

Lastly, you need to ensure that you are targetting the correct element to change the HTML of `document.getElementById('WoL')` isn't an element in your HTTML and thus won't do anything.

See example below:

```js
function check(x, y) {
  var coor = ''+x + y;
  var target = document.getElementById(coor); 
  if (target.classList.contains("bomb")) {
    target.textContent = "You lose.";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-square bomb" onclick="check(1,8)" id="18">?</div>
```